Run-time error '4605': This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is empty or not valid- timing issue?
I have a word template(using office 365)  and copying content & shapes based on some logic into new word document. When I start copying and paste shape , I am getting error message as below

Function code is given below
Function AppendShape(bmName As String, Optional fixPosition As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pos As Double
    showProgress bmName
    AppendShape = False
    
    pos = DestDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    
    SrcDoc.Activate
' DoEvents
    'SrcDoc.Shapes(bmName).PickUp
    '####################################24/05 Newly added
    If SrcDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bmName) Then
      SrcDoc.Shapes(bmName).Select
      WrdApp.Selection.Copy
      DestDoc.Activate
      DestDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select
      'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
      'DoEvents
      WrdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
    
      If fixPosition Then
          DestDoc.Shapes(DestDoc.Shapes.count).RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
          DestDoc.Shapes(DestDoc.Shapes.count).Top = pos + 0
          DestDoc.Shapes(DestDoc.Shapes.count).RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph
      End If
      
      AppendShape = True
      DestDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.Select
    Else
        AppendShape = False
        Debug.Print "Shape not found: " & bmName
    End If
    DoEvents
End Function


as you can see I have tried with DoEvents before copying and paste as well but not luck.
In-fact this code works fine while debugging... Look like a timing issue but unable to resolve this ...
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Have you tried SrcDoc.Shapes(bmName).Copy instead of selecting then copying?  Likewise DestDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault

I've tested your code without issue on M365.
